# Keep getting a type error when using a continuous wavelet transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, wavelet

I'm trying to clean up a noisy signal using a continuous wavelet transformation from scipy.signal as follows:

```
df2=signal.cwt(df, np.arange(1,31), 'gaus1')
```

This gives me a Type Error: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Why am I getting this error and how can I correctly apply a continuous wavelet transformation to my data?

Comment: should you be using `import pywt; pywt.cwt(df. np.arange(1, 31), 'gaus1` ?

Comment: scipy have a continuous wavelet transformation also

Comment: The method is different `scipy.signal.cwt(data, wavelet, widths)`  .. `pywt.cwt(data, scales, wavelet)`

Comment: If I run the line of code in your comment then I get ValueError: only dim == 1 supported

Comment: df2 = py.cwt(df, np.arange(1,31), 'gaus1')

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong library for `cwt()`

Your code should be using the `pywt` module and not `scipy.signal`

Use the following:

```
import pywt
pywt.cwt(df. np.arange(1, 31), 'gaus1')
```

from https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/cwt.html

or else look up the documentation for `scipy.signal.cwt()` for how to use it correctly:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cwt.html

Comment: Do you now why I get ValueError: only dim == 1 supported?

Comment: Can you make an edit to the question and post the stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to denoise a signal, I would recommend discrete wavelets as they're faster than continuous wavelets and can perfectly reconstruct the original signal thus reducing artifacts from the denoising process.

Discrete transforms have 1D and 2d transforms with pywt.dwt and pywt.dwt2 respectively. There is not currently a 2d version of pywt.cwt, so if your "df" has more than one dimension, you might be out of luck (and since the scipy library uses pywt at it's core I doubt that will work for you either).

There is another wavelet library pycwt, that is independent of pywt that might work for you, but I don't have much experience with that library.